# How to train a trained model with new examples in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm working on a machine learning classification task in which I have trained many models with different algorithms in scikit-learn and Random Forest Classifier performed the best. Now I want to train the model further with new examples but if I train the same model by calling the fit method on new examples then it will start training the model from beginning by erasing the old parameters. 
So, how can I train the trained model by training it with new examples in scikit-learn?

I got some idea by reading online to pickle and unpickle the model but how would it help I don't know.

Comment: Maybe something proposed here will help
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/28512/train-new-data-to-pre-trained-model

Comment: I have checked that page before asking my question here and the answers to that question are not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [incremental learning](https://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/scaling_strategies.html#incremental-learning) and estimators implementing the `partial_fit` API.

Answer (score 0):

[RandomForrestClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) has a flag warm_start. Note that this will not give the same results as if you train on both sets at once.

Comment: To train the model on new data I have to create an another model (object of the RandomForestClassifier class) then if I set it to warm_start=True then how can it take parameters from an another model?

Answer (score 0):

Append the new data to your existing dataset, and train over the whole thing. Might want to reserve some of the new data for your testset.

Comment: That is not my goal, why would I train my whole data set again and again!

Comment: Because it is the most straightforward solution. And works the same way no matter how many extra examples are added.

Comment: @JonNordby Is it possible to re-train the trained model with new data? or update the old weights?   or re-fit the saved model on new data only?

Comment: There are two related mechanisms, warm_start and partial_fit. But unless actually training from scratch is problematic, I do not recommend them. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/68756/54096